# Как правильно сделать фон для блоков?

Tags: html, css

Я хочу, чтоб оба блока соединились к нижней части сайта (footer). Стили CSS:

```
/** block **/
.block {
    background: url("../images/block.png") repeat-y -193px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    width: 193px;
}
.bt {
    background: url("../images/block.png");
    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 29px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bt span {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 2px 0px 8px;
}
.dcont {
    padding: 0px 8px;
    width: 177px;
}
.bbut {
    background: url("../images/block.png") no-repeat 80% 80%;
    height: 0px;
}
```

Рисунок:

[image]

Comment: Верстку в студию)

Comment: надо было отвечать как-то типа, ответ там - гугл =)

Comment: юзай таблицу или js

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы это сделать, нужно для левого блока сайта сделать height: 100%, а в этом блоке создать еще 2, где у одного сделать height: 80%, а у другого height: 20%, по идее это должно решить проблему